# Access BIOS while Latitude is docked

Tags: bios, dock, dell-latitude

I have an E6420 ATG in a Dell dock / port replicator No peripherals are connected directly to the laptop, everything is connected to the dock and the lid stays closed. BIOS vA16.
Peripherals are pretty standard:
Single external Dell monitor connected via DVI. kb, mouse, webcam & speakers.

When I press the power button the laptop will power on but the screen will remain blank until the Windows logo displays.  I do not see the POST or have the option to boot into the BIOS or change the boot order.

What setting can I change to see the POST and boot options while the laptop is docked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the NVidia display.  Two options that seem to work:

- use VGA
- disable Optimus Technology

In this case I disabled Optimus Technology in the BIOS and have not experienced any negative side effects.  The BIOS and POST is now visible during boot, albeit at a strange resolution, and I can access the boot menu.

Source:
http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/pre-boot-display-dell-e6320-docking-station

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your LCD panel response time is greater than your Dell system's BIOS POST time.  If you turned on the machine and immediately started hitting F2, (even though the screen is blank) I think you'd be in the Setup program when your external LCD finally caught up.

Anyway, you can extend the system's POST time by entering Setup (press F2 during POST) and changing this option:

```
POST Behavior/Fastboot:  change to "Thorough"
```

You could undock the system and use the internal LCD/keyboard to press F2 and enter Setup, save the change, and then dock again, booting with the new setting.