# Dual boot Linux and Windows in a laptop with a broken screen [HP]

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, grub, grub2

I know there are a lot of similar questions to this one (especially related to display GRUB or the BIOS in a external monitor) but none of the given answers have solved my problem, so I thought this possible solution.

### The problem

First of all, I have a HP Pavilion 15-cb0xx with a broken screen so I have it connected to an external HDMI monitor. When it loads, the OS does show up on the monitor but, before that, nothing (not even the BIOS).

What I want is to have both Ubuntu and Windows in dual boot. My PC has UEFI and a GPT partiton scheme.

In order to display the BIOS in my external monitor I tried all the things that are said in these forums without success, including: unplug the original laptop screen, close the lid, press FN + F keys in BIOS, etc

I have recently been able to install Ubuntu. I could access the live USB from a Windows feature that reboots the system and forces to boot from the pen drive (without changing anything in the BIOS).

The problem now is that GRUB does not show up and if I go "blind" the only thing I managed to do (after many tries) is to boot Windows. If I do not press any key when I am in GRUB, Ubuntu does not load, even if I press ENTER a few times and type the password.

### First approach

I can read linux files of my ext4 Ubuntu partition in Windows with a software called *Linux Reader* and I saw that in the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file I have this:

```bash
menuentry 'Ubuntu'
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic'
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic (recovery mode)'
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic'
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic (recovery mode)'
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)'
```

So I figured that when I'm in GRUB I have to press 5 times the down key to boot windows. Is this correct or I just was lucky?

### My idea

I've seen this post [Display grub on external monitor with docking station](https://superuser.com/questions/1583625/display-grub-on-external-monitor-with-docking-station), so I came up with the following idea:

Can I modify the `/etc/default/grub` file on Windows to add the following line?

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=HDMI-1:D"`

I can re-install Ubuntu to run a terminal in order to see  results of the `xrandr` query (instead of writting `HDMI-1`).

Modifying it from Linux is not an option because I cannot access Ubuntu (nothing shows up on my monitor when I do "blind" tests in GRUB) and with live USB I can only select the installation option. Maybe I could try to select another option in the live USB in order to run a terminal and try to modify this file, but I don't think the terminal will be displayed on the monitor (like anything else).

### Edit

I have already successfully re-installed Ubuntu. Now I can boot Windows and Ubuntu: *enter* key (or doing nothing) to load Ubuntu and pressing *down* key 5 times (like I said before) to boot Windows. Everything works properly. The only thing wrong is that I still don't see GRUB on the monitor and I have to go "blind" mode.

If a run the command `xrandr` in a terminal I get this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99
```

and some more resolutions.

I tried to modify the `/etc/default/grub` file in these two ways unsuccessfully:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=XWAYLAND0:D"`

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=XWAYLAND0:e"`

Any idea?